# Isolation level in database

Tags: database, performance, isolation-level

I understand isolation level concept. But how do you set it and where? I have never seen it in java programs to mess with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) interface.
It defines the constants TRANSACTION_XXX which can be used with the setTransactionIsolation() method.

Comment: @javaguy the user of this interface, which also might be a connection pool implementation used by a jee server. Persistance api usually provide configuration parameters, or do you mean something different by DB engine?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a default isolation level, determined by the combination of the Java software used to access the DBMS and the DBMS itself.  Generally, it is likely to work at a high level of isolation (SERIALIZABLE in the SQL Standard), but you can change the level at which you work using methods such as the one identified by [stacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241590/stacker).

There may also be DBMS-specific statements you can use.  The SQL Standard provides SET TRANSACTION as a preparable statement; you may find you have a statement such as SET ISOLATION too.